# -o-transition: margin 200ms ease-out not working in windows machine

Tags: html, css, transactions

`-o-transition: margin 200ms ease-out` not working in windows machine

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

nav.sidebar,
.main {
  -webkit-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
  transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
}

.main {
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 765px) {
  .main {
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    margin-left: 40px;
    float: right;
  }
  nav.sidebar:hover+.main {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
  nav.sidebar.navbar.sidebar>.container .navbar-brand,
  .navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  nav.sidebar .navbar-brand,
  nav.sidebar .navbar-header {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  nav.sidebar a {
    padding-right: 13px;
  }
  nav.sidebar .navbar-nav>li:first-child {
    border-top: 1px #e5e5e5 solid;
  }
  nav.sidebar .navbar-nav>li {
    border-bottom: 1px #e5e5e5 solid;
  }
  nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  nav.sidebar .navbar-collapse,
  nav.sidebar .container-fluid {
    padding: 0 0px 0 0px;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    color: #777;
  }
  nav.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -160px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  nav.sidebar li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav.sidebar:hover {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  .forAnimate {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1330px) {
  .main {
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
  nav.sidebar {
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: left;
  }
  nav.sidebar .forAnimate {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
  color: #CCC;
  background-color: transparent;
}

nav:hover .forAnimate {
  opacity: 1;
}

section {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Usuarios <span class="caret"></span><span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu forAnimate" role="menu">
            <li><a href="{{URL::to('createusuario')}}">Crear</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Modificar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Reportar</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Informes</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Libros<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tags<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-tags"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/side-menu-on-hover

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for -

I just removed

```
  nav.sidebar {
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: left;
  }
```

from your `@media (min-width: 1330px)` and now its wokring fine. Please do check the answer in full screen to check. Hope this was helpfull fro you.

```css
body,
html {
  height: 100%;
}

nav.sidebar,
.main {
  -webkit-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
  -moz-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
  -o-transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
  transition: margin 200ms ease-out;
}

.main {
  padding: 10px 10px 0 10px;
}

@media (min-width: 765px) {
  .main {
    position: absolute;
    width: calc(100% - 40px);
    margin-left: 40px;
    float: right;
  }
  nav.sidebar:hover+.main {
    margin-left: 200px;
  }
  nav.sidebar.navbar.sidebar>.container .navbar-brand,
  .navbar>.container-fluid .navbar-brand {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  nav.sidebar .navbar-brand,
  nav.sidebar .navbar-header {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  nav.sidebar a {
    padding-right: 13px;
  }
  nav.sidebar .navbar-nav>li:first-child {
    border-top: 1px #e5e5e5 solid;
  }
  nav.sidebar .navbar-nav>li {
    border-bottom: 1px #e5e5e5 solid;
  }
  nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu {
    position: static;
    float: none;
    width: auto;
    margin-top: 0;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 0;
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
  }
  nav.sidebar .navbar-collapse,
  nav.sidebar .container-fluid {
    padding: 0 0px 0 0px;
  }
  .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a {
    color: #777;
  }
  nav.sidebar {
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -160px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
  }
  nav.sidebar li {
    width: 100%;
  }
  nav.sidebar:hover {
    margin-left: 0px;
  }
  .forAnimate {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1330px) {
  .main {
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    margin-left: 200px;
  }

  nav.sidebar .forAnimate {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:hover,
nav.sidebar .navbar-nav .open .dropdown-menu>li>a:focus {
  color: #CCC;
  background-color: transparent;
}

nav:hover .forAnimate {
  opacity: 1;
}

section {
  padding-left: 15px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-sidebar-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span></a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Usuarios <span class="caret"></span><span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu forAnimate" role="menu">
            <li><a href="{{URL::to('createusuario')}}">Crear</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Modificar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Reportar</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Informes</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Libros<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tags<span style="font-size:16px;" class="pull-right hidden-xs showopacity glyphicon glyphicon-tags"></span></a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Hi, I am having one more doubt. I am not able to add multi level menu to this. I need, 4 level menus.

Comment: @Raru please create a new Question defining your issue. This time please be specific about what is your issue and what are the methods you tried to solve it(*this is the format of the ideal question in StackOverflow*).